# NetworkStream Read Extremely Slow

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networkstream

I'm using a C# `NetworkStream` to read/write to an IP address (not a DNS address).
My program is replacing a very old assembly language program that was on a mainframe. Now it's on Windows.

I'm writing/reading less than `200` bytes. The strings end with a `LineFeed` character so I'm using a `StreamReader.Readline()` to read a response, after my `Stream.Write()`. On the IBM a write/read cycle took `300ms`.

Now about after every 2nd or 3 read, it takes `15` seconds for the read.  When I read the log of the sender it is sending the data in less than a second.  For some reason I get these `15` second delays.

I'm clueless on what's happening.

p.s.
One weird thing I noticed if I set the stream read timeout to 4 seconds, it times out around 4 seconds. If I set the timeout to 10 seconds or no timeout, it times out after 15 seconds.

```
TcpClient tcpc = null;
NetworkStream stream = null;
StreamReader sr = null;

tcpc = new TcpClient();
tcpc.NoDelay = true;
tcpc.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
tcpc.Connect("172.18.10.100", 4004);

stream = tcpc.GetStream();
sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII);
sr.Peek();

string Message = null;
Message = "IX3543543" + '\r';
stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Message), 0, Message.Length);
string readmsg = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    readmsg = sr.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Did you try to read data with lesser size? Say by 16 bytes? May be your mainframe maintains the connection and because of this it becomes delay.

Comment: I'm writing to a terminal server, that has a server behind it.  My program is replacing the mainframe program.  I establish the connection and never close it or the stream.  Netstat -n -t 2 shows the connection is staying open.  The connection never goes into a wait_state.  I'm also thinking it some kind of weird Windows thing or an anti-virus program or something.  However, I ran my program on a server and a laptop with the same results.  So I'm at a loss.

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: TcpClient tcpc = null;    
  NetworkStream stream = null;  
StreamReader sr = null;  
tcpc = new TcpClient();  
       
tcpc.NoDelay = true;    
tcpc.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;  
  
tcpc.Connect("172.18.10.100", 4004);
stream = tcpc.GetStream();
  
sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII);  
sr.Peek();  
  
string Message = null;  
  
Message = "IX3543543" +  '\r';  
  
stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Message), 0,   Message.Length);       
string readmsg = null;  
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)  
        readmsg = sr.ReadLine();

Comment: I have no experience using TcpClient or NetworkStream, but a fair amount of experience with using Socket directly. Your application looks like it might be simple enough to use Socket.Receive() and Socket.Send() as blocking calls. Can't guarantee that will fix your problem though ...

Answer (score 0):

Your connection stays open as your code never free your [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) resources.

1. I think that your code should run faster if you add the `using` constructure.
2. Also you can merge declaration and assignment, like this (this is only a style comment, the main concern is `IDisposable usage)
3. And you can [`ReadToEnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx) your message in return, and examine it by youself after releasing the resources.

So your code could look something like this:

```
string response = null;
using(var tcpc = new TcpClient())
{
    tcpc.NoDelay = true;
    tcpc.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
    tcpc.Connect("172.18.10.100", 4004);

    using (var stream = tcpc.GetStream())
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        sr.Peek();

        var Message = "IX3543543" + '\r';
        stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Message), 0, Message.Length);
        response = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

// examine message here
var lines = response.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: This is a 7x24 program, so I don't want to close the stream or the connection.     
The real code is a couple thousand lines, because database writes and reads are happening.  So doing Using statements isn't practical. I just gave the simplest example possible to illustrate the problem

Comment: If you don't close the connection why are you surprised that it's is open? The best way to achieve performance is close connection as soon as possible, and, if needed, open another one.

Comment: I did a network trace.

I found that in the c# code I do a send.

15 seconds later it shows up in the NetMonitor trace as sent.

I disabled Symantec Endpoint Protection, no change.

Comment: Still suggest you to close connection as soon as possible. Reopen is better than constant opening.